# WebView mouse wheel scrolling issue in Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-8, webview, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I am using a ListView and a WebView in single page. Now the problem is that I am unable to scroll using mouse wheel in WebView if I keep switching between ListView and WebView. In order to scroll WebView I have to click on it first which I don't want. I found lot of people are facing the same problem but there is no suitable answer. Following are some of them:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/7f1ac033-eaba-495a-92a5-699acaaa5484/
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/753422/webview-in-windows-8-does-not-gain-focus-automatically-when-hovering-mouse-back-to-it

I found out Yahoo mail app in store. It has the similar interface as mine (ListView and a preview) and works flawlessly. There is no problem in scrolling if you switch between ListView and preview. I am not able to find if they are using the WebView or some other HTML control.

Answer (score 0):

Different UI stacks don't usually work well together and Yahoo! Mail is an html app so it doesn't suffer from that problem.  If you don't need the `WebView` to animate you could try switching it to a `WebViewBrush` when it is inactive and only show the actual `WebView` when it's updating content. Then you could perhaps handle mouse events on a `Rectangle` filled with that `WebViewBrush` by invoking some JavaScript in the `WebView` to scroll the content. Other than that I think while there might be some other hacks to get it to work perfectly - but it might take you days if not weeks of research that is still likely to fail.

Comment: Even I was expecting that Yahoo mail is an html app. That's why it is working flawlessly.

Comment: One more solution is to get rid of the `WebView` completely. In some cases you can parse the HTML and convert it to a XAML layout.